# Zeppelin Spark interpreter throw java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-zeppelin

I have a cluster with hadoop 2.2, spark 2.1.1, hive 2.1.1, Zeppelin 0.7.2

In zeppelin spark paragraph, I executed with `%spark  1+1`

Excepions came in the following logs. How it comes? Any ideas?

> INFO [2017-06-23 06:26:40,727] ({pool-2-thread-4}
>   HiveMetaStoreClient.java[open]:376) - Trying to connect to metastore
>   with URI thrift://192.168.1.138:9083  INFO [2017-06-23 06:26:40,856]
>   ({pool-2-thread-4} HiveMetaStoreClient.java[open]:472) - Connected to
>   metastore. ERROR [2017-06-23 06:26:40,997] ({pool-2-thread-4}
>   Utils.java[invokeMethod]:40) 
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkSession(SparkInterpreter.java:361)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkSession(SparkInterpreter.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:826)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:491)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)  at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating
>   'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:981)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:878)
>     ... 20 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:978)
>     ... 30 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error
>   while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.(SharedState.scala:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState(SparkSession.scala:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.(SessionState.scala:157)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.(HiveSessionState.scala:32)
>     ... 35 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:166)
>     ... 43 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:358)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
>     ... 48 more Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider.getProxy()Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/retry/FailoverProxyProvider$ProxyInfo;
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.(RetryInvocationHandler.java:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.(RetryInvocationHandler.java:64)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryProxy.create(RetryProxy.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:147)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:510)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:453)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2596)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.(HiveClientImpl.scala:188)
>     ... 56 more  INFO [2017-06-23 06:26:40,998] ({pool-2-thread-4}
>   SparkInterpreter.java[createSparkSession]:362) - Created Spark session
>   with Hive support ERROR [2017-06-23 06:26:40,998] ({pool-2-thread-4}
>   Job.java[run]:181) - Job failed java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext_2(SparkInterpreter.java:391)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:380)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:146)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:828)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:491)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)  at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)  INFO [2017-06-23
>   06:26:40,999] ({pool-2-thread-4}
>   SchedulerFactory.java[jobFinished]:137) - Job
>   remoteInterpretJob_1498199191018 finished by scheduler
>   org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter1807637042